# Alternative for creating CreatingUserField, created_date, updated_by & updated_date in Django2.1

Tags: django-2.1

1 for one of my application, previously i used django 1.10 and to track models created by, updated by i used audit_log but it is not working in django 2.1. I am getting the below error so can you guys suggest me how to achieve model created by, updated by tracking in Models.

```
    from audit_log.models.fields import CreatingUserField, LastUserField
    class AuthStampedModel(Model):

    created_by = CreatingUserField(verbose_name = _("created by"), related_name = "created_%(app_label)s_%(class)s_set")
    super(LastUserField, self).__init__(to = to, null = null, editable = editable, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'on_delete'
```

Here is my code -

```
class Plan_type(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(max_length=250, verbose_name=_("Plan Type"))
    created_by = CreatingUserField(related_name = "SubscriptionPlanCreatedBy")
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,auto_now=False)
    updated_by = LastUserField(related_name = "SubscriptionPlanUpdatedBy")
    updated_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I see this is an old question, but just in case you haven't found the solution yet...

Did you try to pass on_delete with one of the options from django.models?

It should specify what you want to happen with the records in your model if the user who created the record is deleted.

For example, if you want to prevent the users from being deleted when they are referenced in your model:

```python
class Plan_type(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(max_length=250, verbose_name=_("Plan Type"))
    created_by = CreatingUserField(related_name="SubscriptionPlanCreatedBy", on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated_by = LastUserField(related_name = "SubscriptionPlanUpdatedBy", on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    updated_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)
```

These are the options:

source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete

> **CASCADE**
>
> Cascade deletes. Django emulates the behavior of the SQL constraint ON
>   DELETE CASCADE and also deletes the object containing the ForeignKey.
>
> **PROTECT**
>
> Prevent deletion of the referenced object by raising ProtectedError, a
>   subclass of django.db.IntegrityError.
>
> **SET_NULL**
>
> Set the ForeignKey null; this is only possible if null is True.
>
> **SET_DEFAULT**
>
> Set the ForeignKey to its default value; a default for the ForeignKey
>   must be set.